# Query Database from Mobile Service with Respect to Current DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, azure, uri, azure-mobile-services

I am successfully querying an azure sql database from an azure mobile service with the following line of code:

```
var targetUri = new Uri("https://studytoolmobile.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(complete%20eq%20true)");
```

I figured I could modify this to fit my specific objective. My objective is to query the database to return the record whose value in the Notification1 column matches the current Datetime:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
currentTime = currentTime.AddMilliseconds(-currentTime.Millisecond);
string timeString = currentTime.ToString();

var targetUri = new Uri("https://studytoolmobile.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(Notification1%20eq%20" + timeString + ")");
```

The problem is that it is giving me an error:

```
'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'.
```

This leads me to believe it is caused by the new Uri I am using.

Does anyone know what the correct uri to accomplish this would be? Or is there a different cause to my error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct OData DateTime literal syntax. For example:

`$filter=(Notification1 eq datetime'2010-01-25T02:13:40.1374695Z')`

You can get the required ISO format value from your `DateTime` instance by using `currentTime.ToString("o")`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. You have saved my night!